# Unable to achieve particular layout of components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, label, layout-manager

I have been trying to work out how could i achieve such a layout of labels, but was unsuccessful in all of my tries.

[image]

Could you give me an idea on how to achieve such a layout of labels in java?

Comment: If you show your closest attempt and what's wrong with it, it makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired results. This can simplify the layout in many cases.

However, in this case you might be able to use a GridBagLayout. The GridBagLayout allows you to specify the row/column of each component. Start with a two column grid.

The first and second labels will take two columns on two separate rows.

Then the next four labels will each take up one column on two separate rows.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information.